# Neo4Django create node not working in manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, neo4j, neo4django

I have neo4j-2.1.3  installed and server running on my Linux system . I created model "publisher" in my app . And then in manage.py shell , whenever I save a node with

> > > from BooksGraph.models import Publisher
> > >       p=Publisher.objects.create(name='Sunny',address='b-1/196')

a long error pops up with:

Traceback (most recent call last):

1. > File "", line 1, in  File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/db/models/manager.py",
   >   line 42, in create return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/db/models/query.py",
   >   line 1052, in create return super(NodeQuerySet, self).create(**kwargs)
   >   File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
   >   line 377, in create obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
   >   line 325, in save return super(NodeModel, self).save(using=using,
   >   **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
   >   line 463, in save self.save_base(using=using,
   >   force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
   >   line 341, in save_base self._save_neo4j_node(using) File "",
   >   line 2, in _save_neo4j_node File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/db/models/base.py",
   >   line 111, in trans_method
   >   len(connections[args[0].using]._transactions) < 1: File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/utils.py", line
   >   313, in **getitem** **db['OPTIONS']) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/neo4jclient.py",
   >   line 29, in **init** super(EnhancedGraphDatabase,
   >   self).**init**(*args, **kwargs) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4jrestclient/client.py",
   >   line 74, in **init** response = Request(**self._auth).get(self.url)
   >   File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4jrestclient/request.py",
   >   line 63, in get return self._request('GET', url, headers=headers) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django/db/**init**.py",
   >   line 60, in _request headers) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4jrestclient/request.py",
   >   line 198, in _request auth=auth, verify=verify) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
   >   468, in get return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
   >   456, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
   >   559, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
   >   378, in send raise ProxyError(e) ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to
   >   proxy.', error(113, 'No route to host'))

---

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a network setup problem. Can you check what URL the library is trying to connect to and that that one really goes to your local Neo4j Server?

Comment: No man the not so expert at django , however this is the status of settings.py   databse part of neo4j  :
NEO4J_DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':7474,
        'ENDPOINT':'/db/data'
    }
}